# How can retainAll method from Set class NOT ignore duplicate items in the common list?

Tags: java, list, set

There are many questions that are related to ignore duplicate items in a list but I do want to keep duplicate items in the common list from retainAll method from Set.

How could I get all the items including duplicate Strings in the common list?

I want the common list to include the duplicate strings "a" as separate items (list size 5)
:  "a", "a", "e", "f", "j"

but the actual common list returns with one "a" (list size: 4)
: "a", "e", "f", "j"

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("a");
list1.add("k");
list1.add("s");
list1.add("f");
list1.add("a");
list1.add("j");
list1.add("e");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("a");
list2.add("a");
list2.add("e");
list2.add("f");
list2.add("j");

Set<String> common = new HashSet<>(list1);
common.retainAll(list2);
```

Comment: Sets don't hold duplicates. Did you try a List?

Comment: List seems to return the elements as I desire. Thanks for this! @shmosel

Comment: How can I determine if two lists (common and list2) have the same elements, regardless of order in Java? I see question in Python using Collections.counter() but what can I use for Java? @shmosel

Comment: You can sort them before comparing. Or copy them to a set if the count doesn't matter. Or use multiset.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to implement custom `retainAll` could be as follows:

1. Build a frequency map for `list1`
2. Iterate `list2` and check if its element is available in the map, and frequency > 0.
3. If yes, decrement the frequency and add the element to the resulting list.

```java
public static<T> List<T> retainAll(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    Map<T, Long> freqMap = list1
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));

    return list2
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> Optional.ofNullable(
                    freqMap.computeIfPresent(x, (k, v) -> v - 1)
                ).orElse(-1L) >= 0L
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test:

```java
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "k", "s", "f", "e", "j", "a");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a", "f", "e", "j", "a", "a");

List<String> common = retainAll(list1, list2);

System.out.println(common);
```

Output:

```
[a, f, e, j, a]
```